# Kile in Windows

Tags: installing

I am using Kile as my LaTex editor in Ubuntu, and wonder whether it is possible to use the same editor for my home pc having windows 7 also. I already searched in google but couldn't proceed much. is there anyone who has done that before?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://kile.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=KileOnWindows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Kile user, I know it worth it! So, with the KDE release for Windows, the instructions [KileOnWindows](http://kile.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php?title=KileOnWindows)  will actually install an **unstable** version of Kile on your Windows operating system. If you prefer to work with a more stable version, you will have to download the appropriate **'gitStable-2.1'**.
More information can be found in the shared link.